# Creating and use a List of Classes List<Class<?>>

Tags: java, junit5

In JUnit5s using handleTestExecutionException method, provided by TestExecutionExceptionHandler, which is called whenever a test throws an exception that is not caught by the code.

I am trying to detect if we have had a crash on one of our hardware devices. 
These crashes can be detected in several ways, as we have many ways of communicating to with our different systems (Rest, Telnet, SSH, WebSocket, SOAP, etc) which all throw their own type of errors.
So, instead of having a massive if statement that checks each of the throwable was an instanceof RestException, TelnetException...,
I was hoping to make a list of the Classes and just loop over this list to see if the thrown error is in that list.

This seems like it would be more maintainable and easier to read than a giant if statement.

```
@Override
public void handleTestExecutionException(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable { 

List<Class<? extends Throwable>> crashErrors = Arrays.asList(NotFoundException.class, BadGatewayException.class, SocketTimeoutException.class, ConnectException.class, ...);

for(Class<? extends Throwable> error : crashErrors){
            if(throwable instanceof error) {
                //process the crash
                break;
            }
        }

}
```

Was hoping to iterate over the list to determine if the system had crashed.

Is there a way to do it this way, or would it just be better to have an if statement with something like 20 or statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the methods of `Class`. There you can find `isInstance` ;)

Comment: Thank you, I was very clearly over thinking this 